# Network Request Failed while fetching - ReactNative

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

I am getting network request failed wile authentication. I have used ip address instead of localhost. I am running my application in mobile device. Here is my code. In my opinion it's an error on fetch function. May be its error on file_get_contents('php://input') this function as I don't understand what is this php://input is? LoginForm.js(saved in E:)

```
      login = () =>{
    const {userEmail, userPassword} = this.state;

    fetch('http://192.168.0.104/fyp/login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    u_email: userEmail,

    u_password: userPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson);

        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');

        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
});

  }
```

*It's my login.php(saved in localhost/fyp/login.php)

```
    <?php

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$u_email = $obj['u_email'];

// Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
$u_password = $obj['u_password'];

//Applying User Login query with email and password match.
$Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM user where u_email='$u_email' and u_password='$u_password'";

// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));


if(isset($check)){

 $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';

 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);

// Echo the message.
 echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 

 }

 else{

 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;

// Converting the message into JSON format.
$InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);

// Echo the message.
 echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;

 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

*DBConfig.php

```
<?php
$HostName = "localhost";
$DatabaseName = "mydb";
$HostUser = "root";
$HostPass = "";

?>
```

[image: Network Request Failed]

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: _Never store passwords in clear text!_. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You also need to narrow down the issue a bit. Does your PHP-code work if you're posting data directly to it, using something like Postman? Does your request even reach the server at all? (check your server logs). Have you tried returning a static value from the PHP-script just to see if it works then?

Comment: Also, you're currently doing `json_encode()` on a string. Even though it produces a result like `"the string"` which, in the specification, is valid Json, Javascript doesn't accept those. Javascript requires json to be either an array or an object.

Comment: I had done that, which you are saying. Still getting same error

Comment: You have done what? I can't see any changes in your question. You still need to narrow down the issue.